# Wont filter array using predicate for searchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

I have following NSObject:

```
@interface finalObject : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *image;
```

which i'm declaring like this in my ViewController:

```
finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
object = [finalObject new];
```

Then i'm looping thename and the image into object.name and object.image and add this object to NSMutableArray called finalArray.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"language"]) {
        thename = attributeDict[@"name"];
        theimage = attributeDict[@"image"];
        theId = attributeDict[@"id"];



        object.name = thename;
        object.image = theimage;

        NSArray *cols = @[thename, theimage, theId ];

        [finalArray addObject:object];

        [rows addObject: cols];
    }
```

now i need my searchbar.text to search through the finalarray, which i'm doing with this method:

```
-(void) searchThroughdata {

    self.filteredArray = nil;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@",self.searchBar.text];

    self.filteredArray = [[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

}
```

The problem is that finalArray in:

```
[[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]
```

should only contain the name and not the image. How can i do this?

at the moment i get this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection
<finalObject: 0x8c4f910> (not a collection)'
```

i've tried adding SELF.name to the "SELF contains [cd] %@"

Comment: From the looks of it you are only adding one object to the array.  Can you post your full code for populating the array, not just snippets?

Comment: The statement `object = [finalObject new];` doesn't make sense to me. Are you calling `new` on the fully inited object `finalObject`?

Comment: im creating a new finalobject(nsobject) and initializing it in view did load.

Comment: You should rename your class`finalObject` it's very confusing, you should use upper case for the first character `FinalObject`.

Comment: Unless you create a new `finalObject` every iteration of your for loop then you are just adding the same object over and over to your array.  I'm not sure if your final array will be one object or an array full of references to the same object.  Either way I'm sure it's not doing what you want it to.

Comment: Okay now something happent i added the finalobject new to the loop. Now instead writing the name in my tableview it writes <finalObject: 0xc83c34>. how do i set it to write the name instead of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that finalArray ... should only contain the name and
>   not the image

You cannot do that with a predicate. You can filter the array on the "name" property
of its elements:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains [cd] %@",self.searchBar.text];
NSArray *filteredArray = [finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and then, if necessary, create a new array containing only the names of the objects:

```
NSArray *filteredNames = [filteredArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Note also, as already commented above, your code creates only a *single* object,
which is repeatedly modified and added to the array.
Since an array holds *pointers* to its elements, you will end with an array of
identical objects.

The creation should be moved into

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"language"]) {
        thename = attributeDict[@"name"];
        theimage = attributeDict[@"image"];
        theId = attributeDict[@"id"];

        FinalObject *object = [FinalObject new];
        object.name = thename;
        object.image = theimage;
        [finalArray addObject:object];

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

*Update:*  If I understand your comment correctly, you should not create an array
containing the names only. Just create the filtered array as

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains [cd] %@",self.searchBar.text];
NSArray *filteredArray = [finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you access the objects properties, for example:

```
FinalObject *object = filteredArray[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = object.name;
// ... do something with object.image ...
```

Comment: Okay it works now with when finalArray only contain the name, but then the filteredArray don't know what image is associated with the name.